# Advise for how to reduce redundant js code

Tags: javascript

```
//Links to jsfiddle must be accompained by code
var customApi = {
        feeds: {
            getFeedActivities(feedName, feedId, callback) {
                function good(data) {
                    return callback(data);
                }

                function bad(result) {
                    return callback(null);
                }
                var url = `${origin}/api/feeds/${feedName}/${feedId}`;
                callApi(url, null, _GET, good, bad);
            },
            getUserFeedActivities(userId, callback) {
                return getFeed('User', userId, callback);
            },
            followFeed(feedName, feedId, callback) {
                function good(data) {
                    return callback(data);
                }

                function bad(result) {
                    return callback(null);
                }
                var url = `${origin}/api/feeds/${feedName}/${feedId}`;
                callApi(url, null, _GET, good, bad);
            }
        },

        media: {
            uploadTemp: function(model, callback) {
                function good(data) {
                    return callback(data);
                }

                function bad(result) {
                    return callback(null);
                }
                var url = origin + "/api/media?type=photo";
                callApi(url, model, _POST, good, bad);
            },
        },
        //
```

I have a bunch of custom callback functions that could be handled by a more generic callback. I know how to create a generic function to handle the successful or failed api calls but is there a way for me to do it with a custom callback?

Comment: Instead (or in addition to) jsFiddle, **please use Stack Snippets** (the `[<>]` toolbar button) so the **full** content of your question is here on-site and people don't have to go off-site to see the full context of your question.

Comment: Case in point: What does `callApi` look like?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder There's no more context in the fiddle.

Comment: @Barmar: :-| Even worse then.

Answer (score 2):

I'd give myself a wrapper for (or version of) `callApi` that handles the callback. Here's a wrapper:

```
function callApi2(url, model, method, callback) {
    return callApi(
        url,
        model,
        method,
        function(result) {
            return callback(result);
        },
        function() {
            return callback(null);
        }
    );
}
```

then `followFeed` becomes:

```
followFeed(feedName, feedId, callback) {
    var url = `${origin}/api/feeds/${feedName}/${feedId}`;
    callApi2(url, null, _GET, callback);
}
```

Comment: Why wrap `callback(result)` inside a function instead of directly give `callback` to `callApi` ?

Comment: @NathanP.: It's defensive. It **may** be possible to provide `callback` directly to `callApi`, but we'd have to know more to be sure. With the above, `callback` is definitely called with the default `this` and exactly one argument (which is what the OP's code does). If we passed it correctly to `callApi`, we'd need to know that either that's what `callApi` does as well, or that `callback` doesn't pay any attention to additional arguments it receives and doesn't care what `this` is. (You've probably seen the classic error: `["1", "2", "3"].map(parseInt)` :-) )

Comment: *"If we passed it correctly to `callApi`"* sorry, typo, should have been *"If we passed it **directly** to `callApi`"*

Comment: I got it ;) Thank you, I didn't thought of `callback` implementation.